# How to create multiple labels

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to "coding/programming". I'm trying to make a functional program - I call it "a point to pay". It's like those supermarket programs where they register the thing you are going to buy. **So i need to create some labels to register products.**

The code I have:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ''When i click the button

    If CantidadVer1.Text = 0 Then ''this verifies how many Labels i have created

        CantidadVer1.Text = +1 ''this updates the verification

        Dim lbl1 As New Label ''this creates the labels
        lbl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
        lbl1.Text = (Product.Text) ''product.text is a TextBox
        lbl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 80 + 20) '' i add 20 more everytime i create a label
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl1)

    ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 2 Then ''at this point it creates the label but "crashes" (It dosent work anymore)

        CantidadVer1.Text = +1

        Dim lbl2 As New Label
        lbl2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
        lbl2.Text = (Product.Text)
        lbl2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 80 + 40)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl2)

    ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 2 Then

        CantidadVer1.Text = +1

        Dim lbl3 As New Label
        lbl3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
        lbl3.Text = (Product.Text)
        lbl3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 80 + 60)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl3)

    ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 3 Then

        CantidadVer1.Text = +1

        Dim lbl4 As New Label
        lbl4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
        lbl4.Text = (Product.Text)
        lbl4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 80 + 80)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl4)
    ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 4 Then

        CantidadVer1.Text = +1

        Dim lbl4 As New Label
        lbl4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
        lbl4.Text = (Product.Text)
        lbl4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 80 + 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl4)

    End If


End Sub
```

> So I execute it and then it creates 2 labels and then crashes.

It is supposed to create 5 labels .

Is there an easier way to create multiple labels without making the program crash?

Comment: What is the exact exception you get when the program crashes?

Comment: Your first `ElseIf` should be `ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 1 Then`

Comment: Are you also hoping that `CantidadVer1.Text = +1` will increment the text field?

Answer (score 2):

In your code I only see one label created every time.  I don't think the code crashes.  Remember in an IF block, if the condition is met in the first part, it skips all subsequent ElseIf conditions.

With a little research, you'll see that the best option would be to use a `DataGridView` instead of a bunch of labels.  You could simply add a new row for each item. Lets say you have a datagridview named DGV_Product with 3 textbox columns for product, quantity and price:

```
Dim price as Double = 1.99
Dim product as String = "Apple"
Dim qty as integer = 3

DGV_Product.Rows.Add(New String() {product, Cstr(qty), CStr(price)})
```

That adds a row containing "Apple,   3, 1.99"

But if you insist on using labels, This would work better:

1) Set The following variable at a class level.

```
Dim lbl_pos as integer
```

2) In your form Load event handler set the value to 20 less than where you want your first label to appear:

```
lbl_pos = 80 ' gathered from your code
```

3) Then in your click event handler of the button you increment the new label's position by 20 before adding the new label.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 

lbl_pos = lbl_pos + 20  'increment the position

    Dim lbl as New Label
    With lbl
       .Text = "Your Text"
       .Location = New Point(10,lbl_pos) '(left position, top position)
       ' And so Forth
    End With
    me.controls.add(lbl)

End Sub
```

With this approach you can add as many labels as you like without a bunch of If-ElseIf blocks.

I hope you rethink your approach and go with the `DataGridView` instead as it's much more practical and you can add as many rows as you like without hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code .. The line

```
ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 2 Then ''at this point it creates the label but "crashes" (It dosent work anymore
```

should be

```
ElseIf CantidadVer1.Text = 1 Then ''at this point it creates the label but "crashes" (It dosent work anymore)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont set the value for CantidadVer1 in the begining. Its value = "" not 0. so it will be the bug if you dont put 0 to the CantidadVer1.text

the first if maybe like this 
If CantidadVer1.Text = "" OR CantidadVer1.Text = 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

Your PTP is **poorly designed**. All the answers here are trying to solve your problem by looking based on what you've done.

But your model is kinda based on your what's in your view. For example, have you planned how you will retrieve all the added products ? The history is inside your view : good luck with that.

That's why **I suggest to review your design**. For example :

- Use a List in your code behind to save your data. Your button_click should only do that (with some validations).
- Use a repeater in your view. Bind that repeater to your List : and voila. Your repeater will take care of creating all the label corresponding to all the added products.